# how to make the many one in a relationship dominant?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that looks like this:

```
match code (key)
game code (with doubles)
```

and a table that looks like this:

```
game code (key)
tournament code (with doubles)
```

the two game codes are connected in a one to many relationship, and it doesn't let me insert a game code in the first table without having it in the second table, while I want it to be the opposite, where I can't insert a game code in the second table if it doesn't appear on the first table, how can I do this?

Comment: The ultimate solution depends on what you are trying to do and why you defined that relationship. What behavior are you trying to achieve with the relationship? What is the primary data unit without which the others cannot exist?

Comment: I want to be able to to see matches sorted by the game they were in, and by the tournument they were played in, using a query (BTW not every game is in a tournament).   Right now I can only insert game codes to the first table if it's allready in the second one, but I want to insert them to the first table, and then to only be able to insert the one I inserted to the first table to the second table.

Comment: Do not worry about the output when defining table relationships. Just about the data input. Edit your relationship by using the `Join Type` button and select to include all records from your first table and only the ones that match from the second table.

Comment: I tried that, but it still keeps the second one as dominant for some reason...

Comment: It is probably because `game code` is your key on the second table. Is `game code` an auto-increment or a custom value? If it is the latter just use an auto-increment as key.

Comment: Ultimately the reason you are having trouble is because you are trying to use logic that is contrary to database norms i.e. create a match with a game that does not yet exist. If you are not experienced in database design you may want to post a description of the real life problem/data and ask for table structure advise.

Answer (score 0):

In a one-to-many relationship, the one-side is always dominant.

You would need to remove the relationship to allow data entry on the many-side, without having a corresponding key on the one-side.

Then you would need to build custom logic to check the many-side when entering data at the one-side.

Comment: There is no need to remove the relationship, the OP can just disable `'Enforce Referential integrity'`